# Start up eclipse :An error has occured. See the log file

Tags: java

I didn't use it for a few days and it can't start up.

log's following:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2019-10-07 21:58:51.679 !MESSAGE Unable
>   to resolve plug-in "com.genuitec.eclipse.web.imagepreviewer". !STACK 0
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in
>   "com.genuitec.eclipse.web.imagepreviewer".    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:117)
>     at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.access$2(URLImageDescriptor.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor$URLImageFileNameProvider.getImagePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImagePathAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:419)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.(Image.java:687)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:183)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:195)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.get(ImageRegistry.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImageFromURI(SWTPartRenderer.java:220)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:874)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:145)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:51)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:147)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4580)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher$4.widgetSelected(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

Comment: Did you tried to use IntelliJIdea instead of Eclipse?

Comment: ye,  I'm a big fan of idea,it is very cool ,but i just use Eclipse  for leetcode sometimes.